# Отступ между иконкой и текстом в EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-xml

Всем привет. 
Пишу приложение и появилась такая проблема. В EditText нужно поместить иконку и следом пользователь будет вводить текст.
Вопрос: как сделать отступ между картинкой и текстом?
[image]

Вот код EditText:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/keyword"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:ems="10"
android:hint="@string/keywords"
android:inputType="textPersonName"
android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_search"/>
```

Буду рад любым подсказкам! Спасибо:)

Comment: попробуйте добавить свойство `android:drawablePadding`

Comment: Что делать, когда [кто то ответил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте свойство `android:drawablePadding`